# How do I compare 2 dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a string `2021-02-23T06:58:51` that I want to check if it is greater than another date.  When I do the below I get an error.  Tried `CAST` still the same error.

```
select convert(smalldatetime, '2021-02-23T06:58:51') > convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE())

Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '>'.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.040
```

Comment: `SELECT {boolean expression}` makes no sense; columns need to be scalar expressions. You likely want a `CASE` expression or `IIF` to determine what value should be displayed when the expression is True/False. Also, why `CONVERT` to a `smalldatetime`, which is only accurate to 1 minute, when your value clearly has seconds?

Comment: @Larnu `SELECT {expression}` is correct.  You could try `select convert(smalldatetime, '2021-02-23T06:58:51')` it should return you a datetime.  Whether it makes sense or not is a different thing.  I wanted to get a true or false. That's all

Comment: `SELECT {expression}` is correct *if* `{expression}` is a scalar expression. Your sis not. `convert(smalldatetime, '2021-02-23T06:58:51') > convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE())` is a **boolean** expression. Boolean expressions go in the `WHERE`, not the `SELECT`

Comment: I confirm Larnu's words. This is a limitation in SQL Server. So you must use a CASE operator to do so. This is due to facilitate the optimizer to give a correct resulting datatype and to have it with a good execution plan, that means quickly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, columns need to be defined as a scalar expression. The expression you have is not a scalar expression, it is a boolean expression:

```
convert(smalldatetime, '2021-02-23T06:58:51') > convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE())
```

This doesn't tell SQL Server what to display, and would be an expression you would normally find in the `WHERE`. I.e. Display rows where the value of `{column}` is greater than the current date and time.

What you likely want is a `CASE` expression or `IIF`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN '2021-02-23T06:58:51' > GETDATE() THEN 1 END 0 END;
SELECT IIF('2021-02-23T06:58:51' > GETDATE(),1,0);
```

Comment: Yep Makes sense. I will accept it when it allows me to do so.  By the way should I did not understand about "Why convert it to smalldatetime?".  It was a string, I wanted a datetime value.

Comment: @Larnu that is not quite right. A boolean expression *is* a scalar expression (a single value of `true` or `false`, the opposite of scalar is a rowset), it's just that SQL Server won't let you select it or define a column or location as boolean. Annoyingly, booleans are use all over the place under the hood, but you can't define them.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

select IIF(convert(smalldatetime, '2021-02-23T06:58:51') > convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE()), 'True','False')